# Stepper motor troubles

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, wiring, dc-motor

I've been trying to setup my stepper motor with my RPI according to this guide:
http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/07/stepper-motor-control-in-python/

However, nothing seems to be happening, have I've wired my pi wrong? Here are two pictures of my setup:

[image: Picture of RPI]

[image: Picture of Steppermotor-connection]

I've also tried to run this script:
http://blog.scphillips.com/2012/12/a-python-class-to-move-the-stepper-motor/

I'm getting no errors from either of the scripts. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**

When I run the code in the second link the output is:

```
$ sudo python move.py
Pause in seconds: 0.0029296875
moving 1024 steps
moving -1024 steps
moving -1024 steps
moving -1024 steps
moving 2048 steps
```

Notice that the code in the second example is setting up the pins like this:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
m = Motor([18,22,24,26])
```

Is that ok?

**EDIT 2**
Here is another picture of the power wiring of the motor
[image: Zoomed]

**EDIT3**
Here is the connection that solved the problem
[image: zoomed2]

Comment: Your connections appear to be OK, I assume you are using the pictured stepper - a variant of the 28BYJ-48.  Does the stepper vibrate at all when you try to move it?

Comment: No nothing seems to be happening. It is cold and not moving. You are correct about the model of the motor!

Comment: Ummh, I'd expect vibration if the pulses were getting through but in the wrong order.  Just confirm that pin P1-2 (5V) is connect to stepper power and P1-6 (ground) is connected to stepper ground.

Comment: The P1-2 is connected to the plus sign on the stepper, the P1-6 is connected to the minus sign on the stepper. I think I've done it like they have in this guide: http://www.scraptopower.co.uk/Raspberry-Pi/how-to-connect-stepper-motors-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: I've added another picture

Comment: Do the LEDs on the stepper driver board flicker?  Perhaps it needs more than 5V?

Comment: It does not flicker, nothing is happening :/. Maybe I can do some kind of test with an LED

Comment: I'm not familiar with that driver board.  It is shown with a jumper over the two pins adjacent to the power pins.  Perhaps you need to jumper those pins?

Comment: You are a life saver it worked! If you answer it I'll give you the credit

Comment: Good that you've got it going.  Don't see a point in adding an answer though, without the comments it would not have any context.

Comment: @joan I think converting the comments into an answer is more valuable than leaving the question unanswered. Please reconsider?

Answer (score 1):

Type `gpio readall` in terminal and check for status of pins, if it is not `OUT` or not going `HIGH` and `LOW`, then check whether Device Tree is enabled or not. It should be enabled.